# Delete Evernote account through SDK

Tags: ios, evernote

I'm using EvernoteSDK pod in my iOS apps. When logging in to Evernote, in the application can create account from the SDK. But it cannot delete the created account.

Corresponding to Apple rule: [Account deletion within apps required starting January 31.](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=mdkbobfo)

How to delete account in the EvernoteSDK since it's required by Apple?

Comment: I presume what you are referring to with regard to Evernote is a button on their sign in interface that lets the user create an Evernote account if they don't have one.  As per your other question, I don't think this rule applies; If you are creating an account within your own app/server then the user needs to be able to delete that account; i.e. If you are storing user details like name and email address on your server in the users account then the user needs to be able to remove that account and information from your server.

Comment: I confirmed that the rule will be applied in my apps. The information was gotten from Apple developer support side that I've contacted via [Apple Tech Talks](https://developer.apple.com/tech-talks/) . They said that we have to provide account deletion feature if there is account creation feature in a 3rd party SDK.

Comment: Then the best you will be able to do is find the link to Evernote's "delete my account" page and provide a way to open that link from your app.  Personally, I don't think that what the developer said makes sense and their opinion isn't the opinion of app review.  The most you should have to do is provide an "unlink my Evernote account" button.  But, you need to submit and see what happens to be certain.